# Concatenating fasta files in folder into single file in python

Tags: python, fasta

I have multiple fasta sequence files stored in a folder within my current working directory (called "Sequences") and am trying to combine all the sequences into a single file to run a MUSLCE multiple sequence alignment on.

This is what I have so far and it is functional up until the output_fas.close(), where i get the error message **FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './Sequences'**

Here is the code:

```
 import os
os.getcwd() #current directory
DIR = input("\nInput folder path containing FASTA files to combine into one FASTA file: ")
os.chdir(DIR)
FILE_NAME = input("\nWhat would you like to name your output file (e.g. combo.fas)? Note: "
                  "Please add the .fas extension: ")
output_fas = open(FILE_NAME, 'w')
file_count = 0

for f in os.listdir(DIR):
    if f.endswith(( ".fasta")):
        file_count += 1
        fh = open(os.path.join(DIR, f))
        for line in fh:
            output_fas.write(line)
        fh.close()

output_fas.close()
print(str(file_count) + " FASTA files were merged into one file, which can be found here: " + DIR)
```

When i input the directory i input it as './Sequences' which successfully changes the directory.

Not quite sure what to do. I adjusted the code before and it successfully created the new files with all the sequences concatenated together, however it ran continuously and would not end and had multiple repeats of each sequence.

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error should occur before the `output_fas.close()`, and should be seen at the `os.listdir(DIR)` call. The problem is that `DIR` becomes meaningless as soon as you execute the `os.chdir(DIR)` command. `DIR` was provided as a relative path, and `os.chdir(DIR)` changes to the new directory, making the old relative path no longer correct relative to the new directory.

If you're going to use `os.chdir(DIR)`, then never use `DIR` again, and just change your loop to:

```
# Use with statement for guaranteed deterministic close at end of block & to avoid need
# for explicit close
with open(FILE_NAME, 'w') as output_fas:
    file_count = 0
    for f in os.listdir():  # Remove DIR to list current directory
        if f.endswith(".fasta"):
            file_count += 1
            # Use a with for same reason as above
            with open(f) as fh: # Don't join to DIR because f is already correctly in current directory
                output_fas.writelines(fh)  # writelines does the loop of write calls for you
```

Comment: Thank you! But now I am once again experiencing the issue where there are repeats of sequences in the new concatenated file and the for loop continues to run until i force quit it. Any suggestions?

Comment: @heather_l: Did you happen to name the output file with a `.fasta` extension? If so, by calling `os.listdir()` *after* creating the output file, it would include the output file's name in the returned `list`, so you'd eventually reach the output file itself as input and start reading from the beginning of said file while writing to the end of it, infinitely. The current design encourages this problem, but it's possible no matter what you do, so to be safe, you could change the `if` to: `if f.endswith(".fasta") and not os.path.samefile(FILE_NAME, f):` to exclude the file itself from processing.

Comment: After some tinkering I noticed my fh.close() line was not in the correct position to close the for loop hence why it kept running on forever. I changed it to be inline with 'if' and now the code works perfectly! Generates correct file contents and no repeats

Comment: @heather_l: This is another reason to use `with` statements; no risk of getting the `close` in the wrong place. :-)